# I want to delete the canvas space between the first and second lines

Tags: html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to delete the canvas space between the first and second lines.

```
<canvas></canvas><canvas></canvas>... more <canvas>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dk5xewzs/)

and, I want to overlap all canvas by one pixel.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkLjh.png)

Is that possible?

Comment: sorry, jsfiddle link is https://jsfiddle.net/dk5xewzs/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, fix the images because are the second is same as the first (also you can insert `!` before the `[jsfiddle][1]` and `[Like this][1]` to show them as overview). | Also don't insert images as code or the image will lose the hyperlink

Comment: vertical--align:top and then margin:0 0 -1px -1px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply this style:

```
canvas {
    border:1px solid;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    margin-right: -1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
canvas {
  border:1px solid;
  margin: 0;
  width: 49.5%;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Great job! Also it's recommended to use `box-sizing: border-box;` and then `width: 50%;`

Comment: A little bit of explanation would make this answer much better! Please, consider explaining this solution!